# class_exists with namespace not working PHP 7.2

Tags: php, class, namespaces

I can't get class_exists to see my class file.

More annoyingly, if I actually include the class file directly, it moans that I can't include it as the class already exists! Talk about a slap in the face.

There's obviously a lot of parts to this so I'll just try to include the relevant bits :

The class I'm checking for is **Posts.php** in a function inside Router.php

Dir structure :

```
app
|
--->Project
   |
   |--->Controllers
   |   |
   |   --->Posts.php
   |
   |--->Core
   |   |
   |   --->Router.php
```

The class name (controller) is being pulled from a part of the query string and it is tested and working. ie - mysite.com/posts/view will result in the class name being passed as "Posts" just as it should be for psr4.

The part of the router dispatch function where the trouble lies.

```
if (class_exists($controller)) {
    $controller_object = new $controller();

 } else {
      echo "Controller class $controller missing";
 }
```

I've tried including the class directly, like I said, I get get a warning about including the same class twice.

I've also tried using the class constant :

```
 if (class_exists($controller::class)) {
```

But got :

```
Fatal error: Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time
```

And also tried using the full namespaced url to it :

```
if (class_exists('Project\\Controllers\\' . $controller))
```

But again, class not found.

Here is Posts.php

```
namespace Project\Controllers;

class Posts
{

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'It Works';
    }

}
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: try class_exists('\\Project\\Controllers\\'. $controller) and don't forget to include your class eg. use Project\Controllers\ClassName;

Comment: Nope, same.. Uncaught Error: Class 'Posts' not found in....

Answer (score 6):

Cracked it!

Needed to concatenate the namespace url with the class and set it as a variable before I could create the new $controller object with it. So it was passing the class_exists check when feeding it with the namespaced url, but failing on the new object as it was out of scope.

```
$controller = 'Project\\Controllers\\' . $controller;

if (class_exists($controller)) {
   $controller_object = new $controller();
.......
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found where you missed something . You got this piece of code correctly and your code gets inside this if condition however when you are instantiating the object you forgot to use the full namespaced path . So PHP looks for a class called "Posts" that doesn't exist in the same namespace with the script .

```
 if (class_exists('Project\\Controllers\\' . $controller))
```